# Alice <should be><should have been> home by now

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, now

(1) Alice should be home by now.

(2) Alice should have been home by now.

**Question:** Is there any difference in meaning/connotation between these two sentences?

Answer (score 3):

The first one - *Alice should be home by now* - might be said in two different circumstances, generally with different tones of voice.

It would be said in a neutral tone by somebody who does not know whether Alice has got home yet. It might also be said by somebody who knows that she has not, and will be said with some emotion, such as concern or annoyance.

*Alice should have been home by now* would be said in the second case only: by somebody who knows that she has not got home, and is concerned or annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

In both statements, the speaker expects Alice to be at home.

The first statement carries an implication that the speaker **does not know** if Alice is at home.

The second statement carries an implication that the speaker **knows** that Alice **is not** at home.